# Condition variable custom wait function

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable, spinlock

I created custom SpinLock class

I want to use this class in condition variable, but have an error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<Spinlock>&)’
                 cv_.wait(lk);
```

I have error in line  `cv_.wait(lk);`

**How can I support my SpinLock for condition variable?**

I want to declare my own function wait `void wait(unique_lock<SpinLock>& __lock, _Predicate __p)` signature.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> // atoi
#include <thread> // thread
#include <mutex> // mutex
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Spinlock {
private:
    std::atomic_flag lock_ = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
public:
    void lock()
    {
        while (lock_.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) continue;
    }
    void unlock()
    {
        lock_.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }
};


class PrintOrder final {
public:
    PrintOrder(int n, int threadNum)
        : maxNum_(n)
        , curNum_(0)
    {
        startTime_ = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        
        threads_.reserve(threadNum);
        unique_lock<Spinlock> lk(spinLock_);
        for(int x = 0; x < threadNum; ++x)
        {
            threads_.emplace_back(&PrintOrder::background, this, x);
        }
    }

    ~PrintOrder() {
        for(auto&& th : threads_)
        {
            th.join();
        }

        auto endTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto diff = endTime - startTime_;
        cout << chrono::duration <double, milli> (diff).count() << " ms" << endl;
    }

    void background(int x) {
        while(true) {
            unique_lock<Spinlock> lk(spinLock_);
            // wait until it's this thread's turn or curNum_ > maxNum_
            while((curNum_ % threads_.size()) != x and curNum_ <= maxNum_)
            {
                cv_.wait(lk);
            }
            if(curNum_ > maxNum_)
            {
                break;
            }

            cout << curNum_ << endl;
            ++curNum_;
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
    }

private:
    int maxNum_;
    int curNum_;
    Spinlock spinLock_;
    condition_variable cv_;
    vector<thread> threads_;

    chrono::time_point<chrono::steady_clock> startTime_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        int maxNum = atoi(argv[1]);
        int threadsNum = atoi(argv[2]);
        PrintOrder printOrder(maxNum, threadsNum);
    } else {
        cout << "ERROR: expected console input: <maxNum> <threadsNum>" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't using [`std::condition_variable_any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any/wait) fit the bill here?  Or have I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: Your spinlock is very power hungry. Consider adding an instruction to notify the OS/CPU that you are in a spin-wait loop. (e.g., the `_mm_pause()` intrinsic available on x86/x64.) Without that, the loop will use a full CPU thread, which can drive the current CPU frequency up or slow other threads.

Comment: @G.M. I have to support order of threads.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm could you please provede example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) only supports `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`. Use [`std::condition_variable_any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any) instead.

> The `condition_variable_any` class is a generalization of `std::condition_variable`. Whereas `std::condition_variable` works only on `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`, `condition_variable_any` can operate on any lock that meets the [`BasicLockable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BasicLockable) requirements.